# AutoHotKeys Multiple Line variable

Tags: autohotkey

I have a simple script ( *see below* ) which replaces either the string ***arpa*** or ***drpa*** as indicated below.

The ***drpa*** replacement uses a random keyboard delay to make the typing more human ...the ***arpa*** replacement is sending multiple lines that have special characters ( ( , {, etc. ) .

What I would like to do is use the ***drpa*** model of sending the text from ***arpa*** to make use of the keyboard delays that are introduced by use of Random as seen in the example below.

The problem is how to send the multiple lines of text from the ***arpa*** model using the ***drpa*** model. I would guess I just to somehow assign the multiple lines to the ***MyString*** variable ...I have tried a number of ways to do the assignment without success.... ideas ?

```
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetKeyDelay 120

::**arpa**::
Send {Text} 
(

while (iterator?.hasNext()) {
    def comp = iterator.next()
    if (comp.sku != null && comp.attribute1 != null) {
        def row = [
                "sku"         : comp.sku,
                "ProductGroup": comp.attribute1,
                "BusinessUnit": comp.attribute2
        ]
        api.trace("Stream Row: ", row)
    }
}
)

return

::**drpa**::
MyString = This is a whole bunch of text I want to see sent at random delay and duration intervals. 
SendDelay(MyString)
return

SendDelay(text) {

  Loop, parse, text
  {
    Random, rdel, 30, 100
    Random, rdur, 30, 100
    SetKeyDelay, %rdel%, %rdur%
    Sendraw % A_LoopField
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now how to do this ( *perhaps not the best way* ) ...

I just used following line of code - basically parentheses around the multiple lines :

```
    MyString = 
    (
    
    while (iterator?.hasNext()) {
        def comp = iterator.next()
        if (comp.sku != null && comp.attribute1 != null) {
            def row = [
                    "sku"         : comp.sku,
                    "ProductGroup": comp.attribute1,
                    "BusinessUnit": comp.attribute2
            ]
        }
    }
    )
```